# Android ViewPager control doesn't appear in Graphical Layout Editor

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, android-viewpager

I would like to use the [ViewPager control](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html). I have imported the v4 support package into my build path so there are no issues there.

When I insert this into my layout XML it doesn't appear in the Graphical Layout Editor:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#FFFFFF">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="#000000" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/batteryImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/battery" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/exit_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/exit_button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/batteryImageView"
            android:text="76%" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dynamic_background_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/topHorizontalLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/prominentDisplayLinearLayout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/scoreLabelTextView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Blast Factor"
                        android:textSize="30dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/scoreTextView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-35dp"
                        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                        android:text="100"
                        android:textSize="125dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/prominentVerticalLinearLayout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/averageLinearLayout"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/averageLabel"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:background="#55000000"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Average"
                            android:textSize="13dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/averageScore"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="100"
                            android:textSize="50dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lastLinearLayout"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lastLabel"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#55000000"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Last"
                            android:textSize="13dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lastScore"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="100"
                            android:textSize="50dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/demotedDisplayLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/leftPanelFrame"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/MotionMetrics.ScorePanel"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#55000000" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/leftPanelImageView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/swingspeed" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/leftPanelLabelTextView"
                            style="@style/MotionMetrics.ScoreHeader"
                            android:text="Swing Speed" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/leftPanelTextView"
                            style="@style/MotionMetrics.ScoreValue"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:text="92" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/leftPanelSelectionArrow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/select_arrow" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/middlePanelFrame"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#55000000" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/MotionMetrics.ScorePanel"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/middlePanelImageView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ballspeed" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/middlePanelLabelTextView"
                            style="@style/MotionMetrics.ScoreHeader"
                            android:text="Ball Speed" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/middlePanelTextView"
                                style="@style/MotionMetrics.ScoreValue"
                                android:text="1.3" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="35dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/score_border" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/middlePanelSelectionArrow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/select_arrow" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rightPanelFrame"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#55000000" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/rightPanelSelectionArrow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/select_arrow" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/MotionMetrics.ScorePanel"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/rightPanelImageView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/distance" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/rightPanelLabelTextView"
                            style="@style/MotionMetrics.ScoreHeader"
                            android:text="Distance" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/rightPanelTextView"
                                style="@style/MotionMetrics.ScoreValue"
                                android:text="7.6" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view1"
                        android:layout_width="35dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/score_border" />
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+android:id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/blastButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Blast" android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/angleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Angle" android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/timingButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Timing" android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tabBarImageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/tabbar"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not sure why, and I also don't see the UI component in my Palette.

Comment: can you show us your complete xml and how you are populating viewPager?

Comment: I updated the complete XML. I haven't written the code to populate the ViewPager but I was going to use the same example as in the Google Developer Article, so I can go through it myself.

Comment: you have to populate it, for the viewPager to appear on the UI.

Comment: So the actual control element itself, won't appear in the Graphical Layout Editor? For example, I can add view stubs, or buttons etc, and they appear in the Layout Editor.

Comment: nope , it won't appear, until you provide the pager adapter, which has pages for the ViewPager.

Comment: Looks like you are right. You should post this as an answer so I can give you credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ViewPager needs to be populated using pagerAdapter in order for it show up on the screen.

Comment: And how do you do that in XML?